# Implicit form of Burgers' equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I’m having a hard time trying to figure out how $u_t$ and $u_x$ have bern derived from $$u(x,t)=u_0(x-u(x,t)t).$$

I’ve tried using the product & chain rules multiple times but I’m just not getting the derivatives below. I know that something has been omitted in the argument but I can’t figure where it would fit in to begin with.

[image]

Here is the original question:

[image]

Comment: Read $u'_0$ in  (5) and (6) as $u'_0(x-u(x,t)t).$

Comment: @user376343 Oh heavens, I feel so embarrassed! Clearly been a long day! Thank you.

Comment: To check, did the previous comment answer your question? It's not exactly clear.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, it did.